# How do I call toString on a JS Proxy js object, not the proxy object itself

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I have a js Proxy object pointing to a jQuery object in javascript, this particular object has its own toString method natively defined. How do I call this? Assuming my Proxy is called _context then this

```
_context.toString();
```

returns the string from the toString() on the Proxy object, not the result of the toString() on the target object itself. Is it possible to pass this through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_context.toString()` will call on js side `String(_contextJs)` which is almost equivalent to `_contextJs.toString()` (except that `null` and `undefined` are handled). If this Js call throws an exception the default [Object.toString](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/Object.html#toString) is called. See the code on [JsObject.toString](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_js/JsObject.html#toString).